# SSIS - How create transaction with rollback

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactions

I want to make **transaction** includes all the **Container** that if it fails it will **ROLLBACK**.

When I switch on the field of **Container**: **transactionoption** 
To "**Required**" I cannot run the PACKAGE. 
What could be the problem? 
And is this the way to do transaction for **Container**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following steps to successfully configure the Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) for high availability (Windows Server 2008):

---

1. To start the Failover Cluster Management program, click Start, Programs, Administrative Tools, and then click Failover Cluster Management.
2. In the left hand pane, right-click Failover Cluster Management, and then click Manage a Cluster.
3. In the Select a cluster to manage dialog box, enter the cluster to be managed, and then click OK.
4. To start the High Availability Wizard, in the left pane click to expand the cluster, right-click Services and Applications, and then click Configure a Service or Application.
5. If the Before You Begin page of the High Availability Wizard is displayed, click Next.
6. On the Select Service or Application page, click Distributed Transaction Coordinator, and then click Next.
7. On the Client Access Point page, enter a value for Name, enter an available IP address under Address, and then click Next.
8. On the Select Storage page, click to select a disk resource and then click Next.
9. On the Confirmation page, click Next.
10. On the Summary page, click Finish.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897479%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)